# Search For user Form Caption

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search for a User form  using caption in Excel. If the user form does not exist I then want to display a message box with the message "userform not found". But it is not working.

```
Dim oUserForm As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set oUserForm = UserForms.Add.Caption("Add New")
On Error GoTo 0
If oUserForm Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The Userform was not found.", vbExclamation, "Error"

Else   

End If
```

Comment: This form that you are searching is in Access or excle?

Comment: Excel What I need is it to search for it By caption name

Comment: Your question says one thing, but your code says another.  `UserForms.Add` implies you are creating a new form, not searching for an existing form, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code. Loop all the forms in the Excel file and search for the form by name:

```
Dim UForm As Object
Dim strFormName As sting

strFormName = "FormName" ' replace this string

IsUserFormLoaded = False
For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms
    If UForm.name = strFormName Then
        MsgBox "Form exist"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That Search's for the name not caption

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are confusing the concepts of `UserForm` and Form Class Module.  This is not surprising by the way because it is quite confusing.

The argument for the `Add` method in your code is a a text string which is the name of a `UserForm Class`.  This is the thing that appears in VBE in the Forms section of the Project Explorer and it is not a Form, its is a template for a Form in the same way that a `Class Module` is a template for a Custom Object.

`UserForm` is a standard `Interface` that is inherited by any Forms defined in the VBE Forms folder and is exposed in all members of the `VBA.UserForms Collection`.  When you define a Form, you can add other properties such as `Controls` and for example, Name.  There is no Name property in the `UserForm` Interface.  `Caption` on the other hand is included, so you can loop through the UserForms Collection and check the Caption property to see if a Form with that `Caption` is currently loaded.  The `Caption` for any instance of any UserForm Class will be "UserForm1" unless programaticaly set by the code in the `Userform Class` or some other code acting on a particular instance of a Form.

This doesn't fully answer the question because the question is a bit unclear, but perhaps it will make it moot?